# PostGIS Raster: raster2pgsql was not found in /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin

Tags: postgis, raster

I have installed sucessfully *Postgresql-9.3-postgis* on Ubuntu 12.04, following this instructions:
http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt

Having done that, I have spatially enabled a database and all the GIS functions seems to be ready (1047). But I don't find raster2pgsql function in order to import a raster to Postgis.

Is there something extra to install or any setting that I am missing?

Regards,

Comment: ##Have you got the path set up in environment variables? ##

Comment: No I didn't. In the beginning, I didn't find the path to raster2pgsql but finally I did. It is in the /usr/bin folder. Thanks.